# Calling WCF service in an ASP.net Web Form

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

I created my WCF service with Visual Studio 2010, I created the client thanks to svcutil.exe.

Then I created a WebSite in ASP.net Web Form and added the Service Reference.

I dont know how to call a WCF service from my website..

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: just add the WCF service to the website solution as a service reference with a proper instance name. use the same instance name to call the functions within WCF service

Comment: have you refered any article? If already tried, then post what have you tried and how it fails!

Comment: I didn't find any article which is really close to my problem actually

Answer (score 0):

Add a service reference. Check this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb655893%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Yes I already did that, but I dont know how to use its methods..
And I'm not Using Web Form application but ASP.net Web Application (which is ASP.net web form)

Comment: By calling them. If the service reference is `Foo` then call its methods using `Foo.Test();`.